# Pandas select columns by regex and change their values by if, else

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

I have Pandas data frame like this:

```
   a      b1         b2         b3       b4       c1      c2       c3         c4
   a1     0.10       0.0        0.21     0.0      0.03    0.10     0.04      0.0
```

How can I change it to the following:

```
   a      b1         b2         b3       b4       c1      c2       c3         c4
   a1     1          0           1       0        1       0        1          0
```

So, I want to select `b*` and `c*` columns and change any non-zero value into 1 and any zero value into 0. So, first selecting columns by regex then apply if-else rule there. It is also worth noting that all `b*`, `c*` columns are string (obj) types.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex is not necessary, use `str.startswith` instead:

```
filter_col = [col for col in df if col.startswith('b') or col.startswith('c')]
df[filter_col] = (df[filter_col] > 0).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    a  b1  b2  b3  b4  c1  c2  c3  c4
0  a1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0
```

---

Edit: If your "numbers" are strings originally, you can do:

```
filter_col = [col for col in df if col.startswith('b') or col.startswith('c')]
df[filter_col] = (df[filter_col].astype(float) > 0).astype(int)
# if you want keep them as strings after computation:
# df[filter_col] = (df[filter_col].astype(float) > 0).astype(int).astype(str)
print(df)
```

Comment: Hi @Andrej Kesley, I want to preserve the original data types of columns as string.

Comment: @SumitSidana why are you storing numbers as strings? what's the broader context here?

Comment: @SumitSidana Do you mean that the number `0` and `1` should be string and not integers?

Comment: @AndrejKeselyI get `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` for your solution. It is worth noting that all `filter_col` are str type.

Comment: @SumitSidana You can do `df[filter_col] = (df[filter_col].astype(float) > 0).astype(int)`

Comment: @AndrejKesely I am storing them as strings because the machine learning model, I am using ingests categorical variable and these are tags, that is why categorical. Does it make sense?

Comment: @SumitSidana I would store numbers as numbers for as long as possible in your analysis pipeline and convert to strings as the very last step

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `str.match`:

```
mask = df.columns.str.match('^(b|c)')
df.loc[:, mask] = np.where(df.loc[:,mask].astype(float)==0, '0', '1')
```